# How to deploy Custom Object Data into client org using Managed Package

Tags: managed-package, custom-object, custom-field

I have a custom object called Workflow in my dev org, we are creating the data for this object and want to deploy this data into client org using managed package where client should also be able to delete or deactivate once it is deployed. Is this possible? Or at least is it possible to deploy the custom object data using managed package? thanks

Comment: You can do it using `Custom Metadata Type`... Or maybe a post-install script, but then I think you'd have to hard code the values.

Answer (score 0):

Its definately possible .You will need a Developer edition org or a partner developer edition org and you will namespace to begin .

Create the custom objects and fields and add it to the package .

To populate test data you can create a post install script which will be an apex class to generate test data .You can use custom metadata to store the records that apex class can fetch .

Create a visualforce page for the admins to allow them to populate test data and provide delete button to delete the data .